# Zoho CRM api v2 list of required fields for each module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crm, zoho

I am trying to migrate my zoho crm apis to v2. I can see documentation for list of required fields for each module for v1 apis (https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/modules-fields.html). But I cannot find the same for v2 apis. Please help me on where to get list of required fields for each module.

Comment: V2 API also follows the same fields and modules. you can use the same for V2 API too.

Comment: Some field names are different for V2. For example, the Accounts module has field "Account_Name" in V2 api. But V1 api's field is "Account Name" and this caused error while inserting data.  Hence, I need to know what all field names have changed in all modules for V2 apis.

Answer (score 1):

It's now per organization so you can find it in CRM settings(Settings -> APIs -> API names)
https://crm.zoho.eu/crm/{org_id}/settings/api/modules

where org_id is your organization id

Comment: As far as I can see in the link you are referencing there is no indication of which fields are mandatory. It lists the field name and the data type only.

Comment: A bit late but might help someone, the required fields are under 'System-defined mandatory fields for each module' : https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/v2.1/insert-records.html